# how to escape semicolons when writing to csv in python

Tags: python, csv, escaping

I have a list of lists in python that represents data to be written in a csv file. My code for that is :

```
for n, d, p in zip(names, dates, posts):
        writer.writerow([i, n, d, p])
```

However, some of the strings in posts contain semicolons, and this creates new cells in the csv. I've looked online and tried

1. setting quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL
2. wrapping each post string inside double quotes
3. wrapping the semicolons inside double quotes
4. using normal python write instead of csv.writer

Nothing's worked so far. Any help, every online answer to escaping comma's I've found involves (1) or (2) which doesn't work for me. Please help!

Edit: Here's an example of what I mean

When I write the row ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd;e'], the d and e get put into different cells, like:

```
a | b | c | d | e
```

As opposed to what I want, which is:

```
a | b | c | d;e
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What do you mean "creates new cells"??

Comment: Thanks for the tip @juanpa.arrivillaga, made an edit hopefully makes more sense now

Comment: That is not a [mcve]. You need to provide data and the code you wrote to actually reproduce the problem. You are using pipe-character `|` as a delimiter? I cannot reproduce your problem with semicolons. Indeed, I still don't understand what, exactly, your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend using pandas for converting data into CSV as it's much easier and you don't need to care about handling characters.

```
>>> arr = [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":2,"b":3,"c":4}]
>>> dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(arr)
>>> dataFrame
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
>>> dataFrame.to_csv("test.csv",index = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response--tried using a dataframe but run into the same issues with semicolons, it creates a new cell (i.e. in your example, if (0, c) contained value 3;5 it would add the 5 into a new cell on the right, essentially creating a new column after c).

Answer (score 1):

It could be an issue with whatever program you're viewing the CSV with. I had the same problem and it was because I had a checkbox selected in my spreadsheet software to delimit by both commas and semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tab as a delimiter.

You can write the file and open later using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) or [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), setting delimiter as `“\t”`.

It works for opening in Excel or similar programs too.

Example using csv for writing:

```
import csv

with open(<filename>, "w") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter="\t")
```

Example using csv for reading:

```
import csv

with open(<filename>, "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter="\t")
```